# Prove that $f(x)$ is defined and differentiable for $x>0$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $$f(x)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t}dt$$

Prove that $f$ is defined and differentiable for $x>0$.

I have no idea how to deal with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be defined as

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t}\,dt$$

for $x>0$.  Forming the difference quotient $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t}\left(\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right)\,dt\tag 1\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(x+h)t}}{1+t}\left(\frac{1-e^{ht}}{h}\right)\,dt \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Noting that for $h>0$ $$\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right|\le t$$

while for $h<0$  $$\left|\frac{1-e^{ht}}{h}\right|\le t$$

we see that for $h>0$ $$\left|\frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t}\left(\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right)\right|\le \frac{te^{-xt}}{1+t}$$

while for $-x/2<h <0$ $$\left|\frac{e^{-(x+h)t}}{1+t}\left(\frac{1-e^{ht}}{h}\right)\right|\le \frac{te^{-xt/2}}{1+t}$$

Inasmuch as $\frac{te^{-xt}}{1+t}$ and $\frac{te^{-xt/2}}{1+t}$ are integrable for all $x>0$, then we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to assert that

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t}\left(\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t}\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{te^{-xt}}{1+t}\,dt
\end{align}$$

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  - Mark

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

**$f$ is well defined :** Since $|e^{-xt}|\leq \frac{1}{xt}$, if $x>0$ and $t>1$,
$$\left|\frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t}\right|\leq \frac{1}{xt(t+1)}\leq \frac{1}{xt^2}.$$

**$f$ is differentiable :** Use dominated convergence to compute $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$
It can be usefull to suppose $|h|<1$.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see how can I use here dominated convergence theorem, though

Comment: @luka5z: Why don't you try giving an upper bound on $|f(x+h)-f(x)|$ when, as Surb suggested, you know $|h|<1$?

Comment: I still don't see how to solve the second part :(

Comment: Connection with Laplace Transform. If you are once again faced to an integral of the form $f(x)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-xt}\varphi(t)dt$, you will be able to find an $x_0$ (abscissa of summability) such that $\forall x>x_0$, the integral is convergent, i.e., $f(x)$ is defined (unless function $\varphi(t)$ increases more rapidly than any $exp(at)$). For your question, the abscissa of summability  is 0).

Comment: @surb The condition $h<1$ should be replaced, I believe, with $h>-x/2$.  Then all is goos with the world.  ;-))  ... Mark